# MultipartFile upload failed in SpringBoot with an ajax way

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot, file-upload

While uploading works fine with normal html & form way, but switch to ajax, it brokes and **MultipartFile** is always **Null** in debug mode.

```
code below works fine

//html code
<form method="POST" action="/api/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>

//java code
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/upload", consumes = "*/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file, MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity(fileService.upload(file), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the following code **DOES NOT WORK**!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
        var data = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "/api/upload",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

anybody some clues here?

Comment: Any error in browser console ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna with no error in console, it just switch to my IntelliJ debug point and produce the NPE.

Comment: try `data = new FormData()` then `data.append('file', form)`; It's how I've been doing my ajax multipart file uploads with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in fact this is a jQuery question...

just use code

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", $("#fileInput")[0].files[0]);
```

done